# Load html from external file without losing the <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to download some html from an external source, and get only the contents within id `#lay_body_get`. This external source also contains a `<script></script>` tag but jQuery is taking out off from the response. Is there any way to get the html code including the javascript code inside the script tags ?

this is the function :

```
function ocmenu(url) {       
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType:"text"
     }).done(function(resp) {
          $('.new').html($('#lay_body_get',resp));
     });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `dataType:"text"`. Use `"html"` or leave it on auto.

See: [jQuery .ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
>   "text": A plain text string.

Further down on the same page:

> If html is specified, any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved data is executed before the HTML is returned as a string.

### Some other potential causes:

- The mimeType returned by the server isn't text/html

## A simple working example

### file1.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="putResultHere">
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
           $.ajax({
                url: 'file2.html',
                dataType:"html"
             }).done(function(resp) {
                  $('#putResultHere').html($(resp));
             });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### file2.html

```
<h1>Ajax done!</h1>

<script>
alert('script worked');
</script>
```

Comment: It did not help. May be it help: If I use `$('.new').html(resp);` scripts dont copy, but they work on page.

Comment: Yes, its work, but I need clear code from header and footer and display only body

Comment: In that case, my answer is wrong. I accidentally left in dataType: "text" and it still works.

Comment: actually, you still get the script inside the div tags - which is an issue for me because my "script" is html (an angular template) and it doesn't work inside the div

Answer (score 0):

```
$(resp).find('script').each(function(i,script){
    eval($(script).text());
});
```

Make sure you trust the external file..